# Freeze an app with flask and flask-logging via cx_freeze

Tags: python, flask, cx-freeze

I have an app with Flask and [Flask-Logging](https://github.com/nathancahill/Flask-Logging) that I have been wanting to turn into an Windows executable with cx_Freeze, but whenever I try to freeze it, and run the resulting executable, it is missing `flask.ext.logging` which is from flask-logging.

Setup.py

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need
# fine tuning.
buildOptions = dict(packages = ["flask", "psutil"], excludes = [])

base = 'Console'

executables = [
    Executable('app.py', base=base, targetName = 'test.exe')
]

setup(name='FlaskExample',
      version = '0.5',
      description = 'Example Flask App',
      options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
      executables = executables)
```

I have tried specifying `flask.ext.logging` in the packages, but it still doesn't work. What have I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flask.ext` is a deprecated technique for migrating older Flask applications.  The correct way to import Flask extensions is to import from them directly.

```
from flask_logging import Filter
```

`flask.ext` does some clever examination of the path at runtime, which is probably something cx_freeze doesn't expect.